# Views, User type page view ignoring Omega content grid

Tags: views, theming

I have created a view of users with a page display.  When I navigate to that page it isn't rendering Omega's usual id or grid classes.  Instead it is just using Views classes.

For example here is the HTML output for a normal content type views page:
[image: Views content type html output]

And here is the HTML output for a user type page view:
[image: Views user type html output]

Has anyone come across this?

--

Just to add that if you add a block to the content region then the omega template seems to work normally.

Comment: "I have created a page view from the user type." <-- what does this mean?

Comment: When you first create your view it asks you what to show.  From that drop down you can select comments, files, content, taxonomy terms or users (there may be more options depending on other modules).  I selected users as I am working with fields from the users profile.

Comment: Ah, got it. Edited it to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: That is very strange.  Omega's region--content.tpl.php template was bypassed.

Comment: That's good that something wrong is happening, at least its not me been a numpty :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I have found a workaround / solution when using view pages.  I think that the Context module may of had a hand in this, as another site I run, which doesn't have context installed works fine when rendering views pages.

So while poking around Context and its available blocks I noticed that there was a Main page content block.  I added that to the content region and now if I use a view as a page the content region HTML is rendered.